# How to get line-breaking / multirow to work in the caption of my beginner's table?

Tags: tables, line-breaking, captions, multirow, threeparttable

How to get line-breaking / multirow to work in the caption of my beginner's table?

```
\caption{this is my first table's captive caption}
```

I'd like the caption to look sth like this:

> this is my first
>
> *table's captive caption*

How?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage{textcomp}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=1, add-decimal-zero=true, add-integer-zero=true, round-integer-to-decimal}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]


\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{this is my first table's captive caption}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}*{2}{L}*{6}{S[table-format=3.2]}@{}} \toprule
× & TOTALLY bla percentage of bla & {1000} & {2000} & {3000} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Bonjour\tabularnewline monde!\end{tabular}} &
 {5000} & {6000\tnote{1}}\\ \midrule
% × & TOTALLY bla percentage of bla & {1000} & {2000} & {3000} & \multirow{2}*{4000 apples and pears \\ and whatnot} & {5000} & {6000\tnote{1}}\\ \midrule
DDD 1 & 47.6 & 29.1 & 1.0 & 0.2 & 1.9 & 15.2 & 0.0\\
UUU & 24.8 & 10.8 & 6.4 & 0.0 & 3.2 & 4.5 & 0.0\\
× & × & × & × & × & × & × & ×\\
Unweighted average: & × & × & × & × & × & × & ×\\
BBB & 33.8 & 11.3 & 9.1 & 0.4 & 1.8 & 11.0 & 0.2\\
GGG & 32.9904 & 8.60325 & 9.3845 & 0.0495 & 1.43225 & 10.79525 & 0.119\\
DDD & 39.4545 & 9.8695 & 15.3365 & 0.6915 & 2.246 & 10.6705 & 0.5105\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [1] the first note ...
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit**

trying to **center** the two-line headings:

```
\usepackage{caption}
(...)
\begin{table}
  \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, justification=centering}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{this is my first\newline table's very captive caption}
```

... the result of this attempt doesn't look quite right ... how to do it right?

---

**Edit 2**

- How could I make the linebreak happen between two particular words (or even characters), ***but only iff*** the caption would linebreak in any case?

Meaning, the linebreak would be "dormant" so long as the caption is short enough to fit entirely on one line; as soon as it would *have to* linebreak, the break occurs at the predefined place.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

LaTeX uses two passes for the caption. In the first pass the caption is set in an `\hbox` if the result fits in one line, the caption is set in one line, otherwise it is set in several lines. In your case the caption is too short and fit in one line.

A trick: A line break is set and much horizontal space is added to the caption. In the first pass the line break is ignored, but the horizontal space ensures the caption does not fit in one line. The the caption is set in multi-line mode and the line break is executed, but the horizontal space at the begin of the next line is discarded (`\hspace` *without* star):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \caption{this is my first\newline
    \hspace{\linewidth}table's captive caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

An alternative is package `caption` it provides option `singlelinecheck` that allows to disable the first pass that checks the caption length:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}
  \caption{this is my first\newline
    table's captive caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

(The option can also be globally set in the preamble.)

### Centering

The following uses an inner `tabular` (and the default `singlelinecheck=true`).
The with of the table label `Table 1:` is calculated (`\settowidth`) and taken into account.

If the optional argument of `\caption` is not used, the following example also locally redefines `\centeredmultilineincaption` to get rid of the `tabular` and the line break for the list of figures.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\@captionlabelwidth}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\centeredmultilineincaption}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\@captionlabelwidth}{%
    \@nameuse{fnum@\@captype}: %
  }%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\hspace{-\@captionlabelwidth}}c@{}}%
    \hspace{\@captionlabelwidth}\ignorespaces
    #1%
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \renewcommand*{\centeredmultilineincaption}[1]{%
    \begingroup
      \let\tabularnewline\space
      #1%
    \endgroup
  }%
  \listoftables
\endgroup

\begin{table}
  \caption{%
    \centeredmultilineincaption{%
       this is my first\tabularnewline
       table's captive caption
    }%
  }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with centering]

**Update:** This method only works, if the first line is longer.

### "Conditional" linebreak

- Both `\\` and `\linebreak` can be used. In single line mode they vanish,
  thus there should be set a space before: `first line \linebreak second line`, not `first line\linebreak second line`. The latter would become `first linesecond line` in single-line mode.
- Both macros are fragile. If the same line break also should occur in the list of tables, then `\protect` is needed:

  ```
  \caption{First line \protect\\second line}
  ```
- The optional argument of `\caption` can be used for the list of tables:

  ```
  \caption[Short version]{First line \\second line}
  ```

  or a different line break in the list of tables:

  ```
  \caption[Short\protect\\version]{First line \\second line}
  ```

The following example defines `\captionlinebreak` that

- takes care for the space before,
- is robust and
- can be redefined for the list of tables.

If the multi-line caption should also be centered, it becomes more ugly, because `\@makecaption` needs to be redefined and its definition depends on the class and packages. The example redefines it for the class `article` without package `caption`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\captionlinebreak}{%
  \leavevmode\unskip\space % one space before
  \\%
}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    \centerline{%
      \begin{varwidth}{\hsize}%
        #1: #2%
      \end{varwidth}%
    }%
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \let\captionlinebreak\relax
  \listoftables
\endgroup
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Lorem ipsum\protect\captionlinebreak
  dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, \dots}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Lorem ipsum\captionlinebreak
  dolor sit amet, \dots}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

`\centering` redefines `\\` to work correctly, but unfortunately does not redefine `\newline`. Therefore combining `\centering` and `\newline` gives strange results:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
This is some text\newline And this is some text, too.}
\par\bigskip
\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
This is some text\\And this is some text, too.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Why? Bug in LaTeX? Maybe David Carlisle could turn on the light here?)

So better use `\\` in captions or other stuff which should be typeset centered. BTW: When using the `caption` package a line break typeset with `\\` will be replaced by a space character in list entries automatically, so there is usually no need to use an alternative list entry text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\begin{table}
  \caption{This is my first\\table's captive caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum "Conditional line break"**

Using `\DeclareCaptionStyle` one can define different sets of options for "single-line" captions and "long" captions. With `\DeclareCaptionOption` one can define own options for usage with the `caption` package.

So as example I define a new conditional called `\ifcaptionlinebreak` and an appropriate option for usage with the `caption` package which can be toggled with `linebreak=false` and `linebreak=true`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

% New conditional \ifcaptionlinebreak
\newif\ifcaptionlinebreak

% New caption package option "linebreak" for toggeling \ifcaptionlinebreak
\DeclareCaptionOption{linebreak}{\csname captionlinebreak#1\endcsname}

% New command \captionlinebreak which either typesets a line break or a space,
% depending on \ifcaptionlinebreak
\newcommand\captionlinebreak{\ifcaptionlinebreak\\\else\space\fi}

% Own caption style which turns the linebreak into a space for short captions
% and into a line break for long captions
\DeclareCaptionStyle{mystyle}[linebreak=false]{linebreak=true}
\captionsetup{style=mystyle,justification=centering}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\begin{table}[!hb]
  \caption{This is my first\\table's captive caption}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!hb]
  \caption{This is my first\captionlinebreak table's captive caption}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!hb]
  \caption{This is my first\captionlinebreak table's captive caption.
                 This is my first table's captive caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum to the addendum "Conditional line break"**

I just introduced `\ifsinglelinecaption` to the `caption` package, so starting with the very next version released on CTAN the above example document could be reduced to:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\newcommand\captionlinebreak{\ifsinglelinecaption\space\else\\\fi}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\begin{table}[!hb]
  \caption{This is my first\\table's captive caption}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!hb]
  \caption{This is my first\captionlinebreak table's captive caption}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!hb]
  \caption{This is my first\captionlinebreak table's captive caption.
                 This is my first table's captive caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

(The inpatient one can get the recent version at http://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/tex/ )